# CKEditor TypeError: c[a] is undefined in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ckeditor

Im trying to install CKEditor in my codeigniter based website and I have followed this tutorial: [CKEditor in Codeigniter Tutorial](http://nukium.com/developpement/php-frameworks/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/)

But Im receiving this error: `TypeError: c[a] is undefined`

```
CKEDITOR.lang.load/d()                   ckeditor___ckeditor:230
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader</<.load/f()        ckeditor___ckeditor:231
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader</<.load/x()        ckeditor___ckeditor:231
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader</<.load/A()        ckeditor___ckeditor:231
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader</<.load/u/g.$.onerror()
```

The folder which ckeditor folder is in: assets/js/  ( which will be: assets/js/ckeditor/ )

The CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://localhost:5678/assets/js/ckeditor/';`

I have no idea what this error is and I can't find properly answers or fix to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey that tutorial is years old -  it was written for codeigniter 1.7 and they have some notes for codeigniter 2. Codeigniter is version 3 now. Discussion about editors including basic code for ck in this thread: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62576.html Also this looks interesting: https://github.com/moemoe89/codeigniter-ckeditor-filemanager

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. CKEditor isn't identifying properly its own folder. 
So you should set a CKEDITOR_BASEPATH variable before loading CKEditor.

It's briefly said here: (but there might be other places where it's explained better.)
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.basePath

Therefore implementation will be like this:

```
<script>
  window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://example.com/path/to/libs/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

In my case i used `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/app/storereport/ckeditor/';`

Then load the main ckeditor.js script.

```
<script type="application/javascript"/>
$(document).ready(function (){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'product_content' );  // ID of element
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can either include the Ckeditor library in your header and can use anywhere in your project . You can check my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use ckeditor in codeigniter    
  You need   
  1.Ckeditor helper : ckeditor_helper.php file put on system/helpers folder  
  2.Ckeditor-pacakge : http://ckeditor.com/download put on root directory 

 Write bellow code in controller file ex.Page.php      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 class Page extends CI_Controller {  
  public $data;   
  public function __construct() {  
        parent::__construct();  
         $this->load->helper('ckeditor');  //load helper
     }
  //load html view    
    public function add() {   
       $this->data['ckeditor'] = array(    
                'id' => 'format', //ID of the textarea that will be   replaced                'path' => '../ckeditor/',    
                    'config' => array(    
                    'toolbar' => "Full", //Using the Full toolbar   
                    'width' => "auto", //a custom width   
                    'height' => "300px", //a custom height   
                    ),   
                );    
                //Loading add File    
                $this->load->view('page/add', $this->data);    
            }    
    }     

load view file
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 add.php    
  <?php      
  $form_data = array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'role'=>'form','id' => 'pagefrm','name' => 'pagefrm','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data');     
          echo form_open('Page/Newpage',$form_data);  ?>
   <div class="form-group">  
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-email">Page Format </label>  
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea class="form-control ckeditor"  name="format" id="format" ></textarea>
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">  Add </button>
           </div>
           </div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
write js to your view file->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> //manage your path

Here you also validate not allowed blank content not allowed using validate.js
--------------------------------------------------------------------

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // When the browser is ready...
        $(function () {

            // form validation 
            $("#pagefrm").validate({
                // Specify the validation rules
                  rules: {
                     format: {
                        required: function (textarea) {
                            CKEDITOR.instances['format'].updateElement();
                            // update textarea
                            var editorcontent = textarea.value.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, ''); // strip tags
                            return editorcontent.length === 0;
                        }
                    }
                },
                // Specify the validation error messages
                messages: {
                  format: "Please enter page format"
                },
                ignore: [],
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also used Ckeditor on my CI project. Don't use this long way use these simple steps -

1. Export your Ckeditor library in your path assets/js/ as you have already done this.
2. Include this on your html page - 
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` on the top of your page .
3. After the html include script having code as-

   CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );

   /* content is the name of the textarea field on which ckeditor is to be applied*/

Answer (score -1):

```
  //ckeditor_helper.php  
 //put on system/helpers/   
<?php   
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function form_ckeditor($data)
{
    $data['language'] = isset($data['language']) ? $data['language'] : 'es';

    $size    = isset($data['width']) ? 'width: "'.$data['width'].'", ' : '';
    $size  .= isset($data['height']) ? 'height: "'.$data['height'].'", ' : '';

    $options = '{'.
            $size.
            'language: "'.$data['language'].'", 

            stylesCombo_stylesSet: "my_styles",

            startupOutlineBlocks: true,
            entities: false,
            entities_latin: false,
            entities_greek: false,
            forcePasteAsPlainText: false,

            filebrowserImageUploadUrl : "filexplorers/fckeditor_upload/image", // << My own file uploader
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : "filexplorers/inlinebrowse/image", // << My own file browser
            filebrowserImageWindowWidth : "80%",
            filebrowserImageWindowHeight : "80%",   


            toolbar :[
                ["Source","-","FitWindow","ShowBlocks","-","Preview"],
                ["Undo","Redo","-","Find","Replace","-","SelectAll","RemoveFormat"],
                ["Cut","Copy","Paste","PasteText","PasteWord","-","Print","SpellCheck"],
                ["Form","Checkbox","Radio","TextField","Textarea","Select","Button","ImageButton","HiddenField"],
                ["About"],

                "/",

                ["Bold","Italic","Underline"],
                ["OrderedList","UnorderedList","-","Blockquote","CreateDiv"],

                ["Image","Flash","Table"],

                ["Link","Unlink","Anchor"],
                ["Rule","SpecialChar"],
                ["Styles"]
            ]
        }';


    $my_styles = 'CKEDITOR.addStylesSet("my_styles",
        [
            // Block Styles
            { name : "H3", element : "h3"},
            { name : "Heading 4", element : "h4"},
            { name : "Heading 5", element : "h5"},
            { name : "Heading 6", element : "h6"},
            { name : "Document Block", element : "div"},
            { name : "Preformatted Text", element : "pre"},
            { name : "Address", element : "address"},

            // Inline Styles
            { name: "Centered paragraph", element: "p", attributes: { "class": "center" } },

            { name: "IMG bordered", element: "img", attributes: { "class": "bordered" } },

            { name: "IMG left", element: "img", attributes: { "class": "left" } },
            { name: "IMG right", element: "img", attributes: { "class": "right" } },

            { name: "IMG left bordered", element: "img", attributes: { "class": "left bordered" } },
            { name: "IMGright bordered", element: "img", attributes: { "class": "right bordered" } },
        ]);';

    return 
    // fix: move to <HEAD...
    '< script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url().'application/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></ script>' .

    // put the CKEditor
     '< script type="text/javascript">' .
            $my_styles .
            'CKEDITOR.replace("'.$data['id'].'", ' . $options . ');</ script>';
}
```